# How to retrieve data and saved for offline use in android?

Tags: android

I wanted to make an android app where data will retrieve and users can saved those data so that they can read it offline.I know how to retrieve data from mysql but no idea how to add save option for offline use.
Thanks

Comment: for offline purpose sqlite database is very useful

Comment: there are so many ways to save data in Android, so I even can't decide which one to suggest. Why didn't you use search before asking while you had to?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:-

You will prefer the various options for storing data :-

- Intent
- SharedPreference
- SQLite
- Content Provides

> Refer this link also:-http://www.androidinterview.com/how-many-ways-data-stored-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

you can store data in SQLite database for offline purpose.

First fetch all data from server and saved to local database for local database use SQLite.

In offline mode, if you made change in local db then once internet connection available send that data to server.

So SQLite is best way to handle app in offline mode.